# what is the best way to play and setup controls for video (like play, pause, stop, volume and seek bar) on xamarin.ios

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, avplayer, mpmovieplayercontroller

what is the best way to play and set up controls for video (like play, pause, stop, volume and seek bar) on xamarin.ios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually , there are lots of solutions which can implement it . Like **MPMoviePlayerController**，**MPMoviePlayerViewController**，**AVPlayer**，**AVPlayerViewController**...

Note: **MPMoviePlayerController** and **MPMoviePlayerViewController** are obsolete after iOS 9.0 .

The following code are the basic usage of **AVPlayer**

in the method `ViewDidLoad`

```
        //Set the local movie file path
        //string moviePath = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource("xxx", "mp4");
        //NSUrl movieUrl = NSUrl.FromFilename(moviePath);

        //set remote url path
        NSUrl movieUrl = new NSUrl("https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4");



        //Using AVPlayer(using AVFoundation)
        AVPlayer avPlayer;
        AVPlayerLayer playerLayer;
        AVAsset asset;
        AVPlayerItem playerItem;
        asset = AVAsset.FromUrl(movieUrl);
        playerItem = new AVPlayerItem(asset);
        avPlayer = new AVPlayer(playerItem);
        playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer.FromPlayer(avPlayer);
        playerLayer.Frame = new CGRect(50, 300, 200, 200);
        View.Layer.AddSublayer(playerLayer);
        avPlayer.Play();

        // you can add button and slider to control the play, pause , seek and volume
        avPlayer.Pause();
        avPlayer.Seek();
        avPlayer.Volume = xxx;
```

In this way ,  you need to define the UI of Control Element by yourself.

If the url is always remote , we can also open the url in **WKWebView** . It had implemented pause and seek function in default .

```
       //set remote url path
        NSUrl movieUrl = new NSUrl("https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4");


        var webView = new WKWebView(View.Frame, new WKWebViewConfiguration());
        Add(webView);
        
        using (var request = NSUrlRequest.FromUrl(movieUrl))
        {
            webView.LoadRequest(request);
        }
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer.
can you please tell me what is the best way to record a video?
I want the following functionalities while recording:

1. set the framerate
2. set the resolution
3. set camera lens (wide, ultrawide, telephoto)
4. Start Recording
5. Pause
6. Resume
7. Stop

Comment: here is the link to another question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64965525/what-is-the-best-way-to-record-a-video-in-xamarin-ios

Comment: @lucas-zhang-msft how can I play a video by file path (saved in photo gallery)?